# JS - получить всё что дошло до браузера

Tags: javascript

Ищу решение как убрать все левые вставки из страницы пользователя.

На данный момент решение такое:

1. на сервере PHP: ob_start() + ob_get_clean() + функция хеширования получаю хеш для страницы
2. на клиенте, после прогрузки страницы из JS получаю содержимое документа и получаю хеш
3. сравниваю - если отличаются - вывожу посетителю окно с просьбой удалить/отключить говноплагины в браузере и/или вылечить свой комп.

В JS для получения содержимого страницы конструкция:

```
var doc = document || window.document
var content = doc.html.innerHTML;
```

Но, я так понимаю это поиск в DOM модели нужных элементов. Если поверх тега `<html>` вгрузят ещё один `html` или блок/фрейм, то `doc.html.innerHTML` конструкция не увидит этого.

Подскажите как получить из JS/jquery вообще весь код, который приехал в браузер посетителя? Пара часов гугления загнала в тупик.

Или подскажите другие варианты решения вопроса с проверкой целостности полученного браузером посетителя контента.

Comment: Обратите внимание и на интернет-провайдеров, которые вставляют свои скрипты в страницы клиентов. Т.е. ваш пользователь может быть абсолютно чист, но из-за провайдера, который добавил свой код, он получит сообщение о нежелательном плагине или вирусе. Как вариант решения - принудительный HTTPS

Comment: вообще в целом плохая идея.